# Incomprehension between HTML class and CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really new with HTML/CSS and after some tutorials, I'm still getting a problem between my HTML file and my CSS stylesheet.

I would like to apply a `padding-left` to my class `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` in order to put elements from my class to the right side of my navbar.

This is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load user_tags %}

    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>
    <style>
    .marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}
    .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
    .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.datasystems.fr/"> DatasystemsEC </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Home tab -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li> 

                <li class = "dropdown">
                        <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                            Informations Mairie
                        <b class = "caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href = "{% url "Mairieform" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Créer/Editer les informations de la Mairie </a></li>
                            <li><a href = "{% url "Mairieresume" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Consulter les informations de la Mairie </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                <!-- Resume Tab with acts -->

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Actes Etat Civil <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula">
                                    </span> Fiches Individuelles 
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Edition Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Suppression Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Actes de Naissance</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <li><a href="{% url "logout" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Déconnexion </a></li>
                                    <li><a>{{user.username}} </a></li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li><a href="{% url "login" %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Connexion </align></a></li>
                                {% endif %}


                                {% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
                                    <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/admin.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                {% elif request.user|has_group:"visiteur"%}
                                    <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/visiteur.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                {% elif request.user|has_group:"employé"%}
                                    <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/employé.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                {% elif request.user|has_group:"officier"%}
                                    <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/officier.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                {% elif request.user|has_group:"maire"%}
                                    <img style="display: inline-block; height: 30px; margin-top: 10px; margin-right:30px" src="{% static 'images/maire.png' %}{{ user.get_profile.avatar }}">
                                {% endif %}

            </li>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        event.stopPropagation(); 
                        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>   
    </body>   

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}  
</html>
```

And this is my CSS file :

```
/* ###################################################### */
/* CSS File about BirthCertificate application properties */
/* ###################################################### */

/* Define background color from upper navbar */
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #0083A2;
    }

/* DatasystemsEC tab */
.navbar-inverse .container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color : white;
    }

/* Tab properties from navbar */
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color:  white;
    }

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    color:  #454545;
    }

/* This line*/
.nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right {
    padding-left: 500px ;
    }

.active {
    background-color: #454545;
    }

/* Titles properties */
h1, h2, h4 {
    color: #0083A2;
    }

/* Define button properties */
.button {

    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    }

/* Define form fields properties */
.form-fields {
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

.col-sm-6 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left : 10px;
    width: 30%;
    list-style: none;
    }

.col-sm-8 {
    list-style: initial;
    }

.col-sm-10 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left : 10px;
    width: 800%;
    list-style: none;
    }

/* Hoover button properties */
.button:hover {
    background-color: #0083A2;
    color: #454545;
    }

/* Hoover color dropdown menu */
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #0083A2;
    }

.dropdown-menu li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    position:static;
}

.logo {
    position : fixed ;
    top:0;
    left:100px;
}

@justify {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

My HTML/CSS file gives me :

[image]

Can you give me some advices to do that ?

Comment: `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right` should do the trick although you probably only need `.navbar-right`.

Comment: I already try this syntax and I don't have changes in my Django website.

Comment: Well this will definitely work given the example you are provided https://jsfiddle.net/afpbqfb2/ so this suggests that there is something else causing your issue. For us to be able to help you will need to provide code which demonstrates the issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info. That said you have quite a few issues with your markup that should be fixed (e.g. `li` tags as children of `li`, unclosed tags) as these may cause or exasperate the issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space between classes in your CSS file it means `.nav` contains `.navbar-nav`. If you have spaces in `class=''` you asign multiple classes to one element.

If you have a specific class that uses a property, use it alone (`.navbar-right`).

Comment: I have spaces in my class like `class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right"`

Comment: Yes. That means you assign three classes to the element. See the comments above. You can reference to this element with `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right`

Comment: @Andro when you use spaces in CSS it means "search inside" so if you say .nav .nav-bar you are saying "find a .nav and inside find a .nav-bar". Without spaces instead you are saying "find a .nav which has ALSO the class .nav-bar"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
float: right;
```

if you are using bootstrap you should check the documentation and make sure the html tags are all inserted correctly: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Also your class should be:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
```

Comment: well, first of all you are using an <li> with inside other <li>. You should create first an <ul> to contain others li's so for example<li><ul><li>...</li></ul></li>:Second, you should not use again the classes .nav .navbar-nav since they are inherited from the parent <ul>. Please take a look at bootstrap documentation which explains well the use of a navbar :)

Comment: I will look more deeply the documentation ^^

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @skAstro has said, there is a concept failure in your code. In CSS the spaces between each class name represent a hierarchy of classes. For example, the selector `.a .b` matches every element with has a class `b` that is a descendant of another with the class `a`.

If you put in your `class` attribute of a HTML tag more than one word, what you're saying is that that tag has more than one CSS class. For example, if we have this tag `<p className="text info">` what it says is that that tag has, at the same time, two classes: `text` and `info`. That means that the selector `.text`, the selector `.info`, and the selector `.text.info`, matches that tag (everyone with its priority).

In that way, maybe the "best" selector, in this case, would be: `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right`, but you can think about adding another CSS for such case.